# How do I display a Taxonomy Term Description to a view in D7?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I would also like to know how to display a custom field that you add to taxonomy terms.... D7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to add a *relationship* to include the term data for the content(?) you are listing – then the term description will be available as regular View fields.

You can check out [Learn Views with NodeOne, part 11: Relationships](http://nodeone.se/sv/node/673) for a quick video on managing relationships.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! The taxonomy terms description and other fields did indeed show up. Thanks!